# Use PowerShell to add dash symbols to a list of MAC addresses in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I am looking for a script that would add "-" after every two digits of a MAC Address. There is already a script here that fixes this.

```
$macs = Get-Content C:\Users\metho\Desktop\mac.txt
$output = foreach ($mac in $macs){
    $mac.insert(2,"-").insert(5,"-").insert(8,"-").insert(11,"-").insert(14,"-")
}
$output | Out-File C:\Users\nmetho\Desktop\mac1.txt
```

The problem I have is that I am using a CSV file that contains four columns and therefore the above script does not work for me.

```
Description, MacAddress, IPAddess, Location

CJ0001, 00351AC0353C, 192.168.2.5, Room1
```

I am looking to modify only the `MacAddress` field so that I get the "Mac Address" in this format 00-35-1A-C0-35-3C.

Can I use this script to achieve what I am looking for or do I need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tested and works. Per the discussion comments I've included a check for strings that aren't the expected length of a MAC address. This will also ensure it doesn't add further dashes if you run it subsequent times:

```
Import-CSV 'C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd.csv' | ForEach-Object {   
    If ($_.MacAddress.length -eq 12){
        $_.MacAddress = $_.MacAddress.insert(2,"-").insert(5,"-").insert(8,"-").insert(11,"-").insert(14,"-")
    } Else {
        Write-Warning "The MAC Address $($_.MacAddress) is not 12 characters"
    }
    Write-Output $_
} | Export-CSV 'C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd_v1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Your solution works gives me the results i want but for some strange reasons its throughs the error message for each macaddress processed. 

Exception calling "Insert" with "2" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: startIndex"
At line:2 char:5
+     $_.MacAddress = $_.MacAddress.insert(2,"-").insert(5,"-").insert( ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Hi Mark,

I am using your script in this format:-

Import-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd.csv | ForEach-Object {   
    $_.MacAddress = $_.MacAddress.insert(2,"-").insert(5,"-").insert(8,"-").insert(11,"-").insert(14,"-")
    Write-Output $_
} | Export-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd_v1.csv

Comment: Are there any lines in your CSV file where the MAC address is missing, or is shorter than it should be? 

The error you are seeing I think is because it's trying to use insert on a string index that is higher than the length of the string (for example: trying to add a character in to the 8th place of a string that is only 5 characters long).

Comment: I have updated my answer to test if the MAC Address is 12 characters in length and to throw a warning if it's not. (Beware write-warning requires PS v3 or above).

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your help. 

You are right, There are some mac address that are long and vice versa. is there anyway that can be ignored and work on only the macaddresses that are in right order. Or, is there a way to incorporate a solution that does add "-" on shorter and longer mac addresses?

Again, thanks for the help.

just seen your updated answer. i'll try that just now.

Comment: Mark, 

Thank you very much, it works they way it should. now i have two solutions.

You guys are grea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$macs | ForEach-Object {
  Select Description, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }}, IPAddess, Location
}
```

Breaking the expression down:

```
{ `
  ( `
  $_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' ` # regex split the mac address up every two alpha-numeric chars
  | Where-Object {$_} `                  # filter to only return non-blank splits
  ) `
  -join '-'                              # join the 2-char pairs with a '-'
}
```

**EDIT**

And here is a complete example, mixing your code, with mine, to input a file, then output it:

```
# remove comment before -Header if no header
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Macadd.csv # -Header Description, MacAddress, IPAddess, Location
$csv | ForEach-Object { Select HostName, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }} } |
  Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\metho\Desktop\MacAdd_v1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Although, this can be simplified, by not using variables, like this:

```
  Import-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Macadd.csv |
  ForEach-Object { Select HostName, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }} } |
  Export-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\MacAdd_v1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is really good and this is something i can use for other things as well. Unfortuntly, ATM I am struggling to get the results i want. 

$csv = Import-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Macadd.csv


$csv | ForEach-Object {
  Select HostName, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }}
 

} | Export-CSV C:\Users\metho\Desktop\MacAdd_v1.csv

This looks like its running fine but for somereasons the output file is completely empty. 

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks again for the help

Comment: Care to explain what results you are getting? Mine & @Mark's answers should both split your mac adress string correctly.

Comment: Updated the answer, with a complete example, that uses your input and output file. Is your input file formatted correctly and is the mac address column populated for all rows?

Comment: Also removed your username typo in the output file. was `nmetho`, is now `metho`

Comment: First of all Guys, can i say how much i appricate you guys helping a powershell novice. 

This is the script i am using 

$macs = Import-Csv C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd.csv
$macs | ForEach-Object {
  Select HostName, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }}, IpAddress, Location
}
$macs | Export-Csv C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd_v1.csv 

Sorry but the output is still blank, is it because i am using csv file instead of a text file or is this only going to work with a text file.

Comment: Your code should work, assuming `Macadd.csv` is a csv that has a header line of `Description,MacAddress,IPAddess,Location` and actually has data rows. If no header, to the Import-Csv line, you will need to add ` -Header Description, MacAddress, IPAddess, Location` after the csv. You'll also need to add ` -NoTypeInformation` to the Export-Csv (updated my code again).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you, it worked. 

Thanks very much for the help.

I dont know why, but i can only mark one as an answer, strange :-(

Comment: Excellent. Sorry for the hiccups along the way! Please mark as the answer, if it's worked.

Comment: you dont have to be Sorry, you helped me alot, 

This is the final code that worked for me:- For some strange reasons you provided solution just didnt work for me. Do we really need "Foreach-Object there? i mean "Select" does the same thing as well? 
Eventually, Follwing worked. Again, Thank you for your help.

$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd.csv
$csv | Select HostName, @{Name='MacAddress'; Expression={ ($_.MacAddress -split '([A-Z0-9]{2})' | Where-Object {$_}) -join '-' }}  |
  Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\metho\Desktop\macadd_v1.csv -NoTypeInformation